# Scala Playframework 'method invokeBlock overrides nothing'

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I've added keycloak authentication to my Playframework project, but it's implemented only for one Action. I'm trying to create a custom Action class which will be validating the JWT and which I'll inject into all classes.

My current endpoint code:

```
val configData: Config = config.get[Config]("auth.keycloak")
val keycloakConfig = KeycloakConfig(configData)
val kcContext = KeycloakHelperContext(keycloakConfig)

def getUserProps() = Action {
    implicit request: Request[AnyContent] =>

    val user = kcContext.dpKcAuthentication.validateJWT
    Ok(write(Map("user" → user))).as(JSON)
}
```

The custom actionimpl I'm trying to create:

```
val configData: Config = config.get[Config]("auth.keycloak")
val keycloakConfig = KeycloakConfig(configData)
val kcContext = KeycloakHelperContext(keycloakConfig)

override def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[AnyContent], block: Request[A] => Future[Result]): Future[Result] = {
  val user = kcContext.dpKcAuthentication.validateJWT(request)
  block(request)
}
```

And it says:

> Method 'invokeBlock' overrides nothing

It happens when I pass request to validateJWT method. I don't do it in my controller because I simply say that the request is implicit and it's passed there.

For current implementation, I need to make the request inside invokeBlock implicit or find a way to pass it validateJWT method.

Comment: Show us your complete `actionimpl`, it seems that your `invokeBlock` method signature is different to what is defined on the parent class/trait.

Comment: By the way, I'm not sure about your requirements but a different mechanism is to just create a base controller that can handle those kind of details easily, for example, the [playsonify](https://github.com/AlexITC/playsonify) has authentication as a first-class citizen, I have used it to implement this [JWTAuthenticatorService](https://github.com/AlexITC/crypto-coin-alerts/blob/develop/alerts-server/app/com/alexitc/coinalerts/services/JWTAuthenticatorService.scala) which can give you the ideas for porting it to your project without requiring to go with playsonify.